# Select child element of cached node using Sizzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

Anybody familiar with Sizzle?
Is there support for selecting children of cached DOM nodes?
Like jQuery:

```
var body = jQuery('body');
var div = jQuery('#mydiv',body);
```

10x for your kind help, BR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use direct child selector with context:

```
Sizzle( "> *", body);
```

In fact, I directly copypasted Sizzle source code and this worked, so I don't understand the downvotes:

```
var body = Sizzle("body");
var childrenOfBody = Sizzle( "> *", body[0]);
```

Comment: Isn't that very slow?
I can use direct selector, but that's not the point.
Anyway thanks for your cooperation I give you +1 for your effort to help

Comment: @kidwon By "cached", do you mean assigning the result to a variable like your whole post suggests?

Comment: Yes, I mean saving the reference to the node in a variable

Comment: @kidwon Ok, so what's the problem then? If you are in pure sizzle, there is no such thing as `.children()` but the selector with context is equivalent.

Comment: Maybe the "*" selector fooled some people and they down voted you, I didn't get it the first time either, however I don't like the down arrow when people are trying to help. BR

Comment: +1. (And regarding the downvote - which seems to have been removed now - you've been around SO long enough to know that people downvote correct answers just because they're in a bad mood, or they didn't like your user name, or whatever.)